# Google Sheets Query across sheets using checkboxes to limit results

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am making a mini-search engine in Google Sheets. I have information in 3 sheets (6th Grade, 7th Grade, 8th Grade). 
In the past, I had a Combined sheet that combined the information from each sheet. However, as I add additional sheets for grades 1-5, the amount of information returned will be excessive. I want to allow the user to use checkboxes to identify which grades they want results from.

Here is the [workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tSyTpOj3B-7GdgLr39hac_8xz5bsdu_GqqA3__i9Dec/edit#gid=736749666).
I've added sheets for all the grades by copying the data from 6th, 7th, and 8th. The format of the data will be the same once I get my hands on it.

Here is the formula I've been playing around with:

```
=iferror(If(D2=True,Query(
             Kindergarten!A:I,"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 
            ),
      Query(
             {Kindergarten!A:I;'1st'!A:I;'2nd'!A:I},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 
            ),
      "No Matches, try a different search"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not mention what you want to search in Search cell, but the formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({
 IF(D2=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({Kindergarten!A:I},    "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""}); 
 IF(E2=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'1st'!A:I},           "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(F2=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'2nd'!A:I},           "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(G2=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'3rd'!A:I},           "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(H2=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'4th'!A:I},           "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(C4=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'5th'!A:I},           "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(D4=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'6th'!A:I},           "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(E4=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'7th'!A:I},           "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(F4=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'8th'!A:I},           "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(G4=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'9th and 10th'!A:I},  "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""});
 IF(H4=TRUE, IFERROR(QUERY({'11th and 12th'!A:I}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col9>0", 0), {"","","","","","","",""}), {"","","","","","","",""})},
 "where Col1 is not null", 0), "No Matches, try a different search")
```

[image: 0]